# How to display quotes instead of special characters in javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a variable on my html page that I receive from python via flask:

```
var dates = [{{ dataDte }}]
```

and this variable produces the following output in Web Inspector:

```
var dates = [&#39;08/09/2020&#39;, &#39;09/09/2020&#39;, &#39;10/09/2020&#39;, &#39;11/09/2020&#39;]
```

How could I convert the above so the variable values would be showing as:

```
var dates = ["08/09/2020", "09/09/2020", "10/09/2020", "11/09/2020"]
```

Comment: The output you copied from Web Inspector is not valid JavaScript syntax (quotes are missing?). Did `dates` come out as an array with one long string, or with several strings, or still something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `dataDte` is already an array, you should apply the `tojson` filter as follows -- without the additional brackets:

```
var dates = {{ dataDte|tojson }};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

`unescape("&#39;08/09/2020&#39;")`
which results in: `'08/09/2020'`.

Or for the whole array:

```
dates.map((date) => unescape(date));
```